# How to improve rendering of surface water in shaded-relief images

Tags: texture, lighting

I asked a version of this question on [GIS Stack Exchang](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/425189/seeking-ways-to-improve-rendering-of-surface-water-in-shaded-relief-images)e three months ago, but did not receive an answer. So I am posting it here.

I’ve written a simple Java application for rendering high-resolution terrestrial elevation data from the U.S. Geological Survey.  The algorithms, lighting model, and data sources I use are described in [Elevation from Cloud-Optimized GeoTIFFs (Parts 1 and 2)](https://gwlucastrig.github.io/GridfourDocs/notes/ElevationGeoTiff1.html).

While I have gotten satisfactory results for terrain, I’d like to improve the rendering of surface water (which is comes from a polygon-based dataset).  Can anyone recommend techniques that can be implemented with a reasonable effort?

I’m not looking for a high-level of realism. Unfortunately, the flat surfaces I render don’t harmonize well with the terrain (I’ve attached a picture to show what I’m talking about).  So I am looking for something that will reduce the dissonance between the two kinds of data.

Thank you in advance for your consideration.

[image: Shaded-relief image in a 2D map]

Comment: You can use exponential decay for the blending of the water and the terrain below it. Look up Beer-Lambert's law. To measure the distance per pixel between the water and terrain you could render the two separately and then subtract their depth to find the attenuation distance.

Comment: Do you have elevation data for the water regions? (I have seen a lot of maps that do have that info is why I ask) Doing a similar rendering using shades of blue for the water could be a nice enhancement, and if the code setup allows, alpha blending the current flat  shaded surface could help visualize the actual surface of the water. (looks good btw)

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions.   In this particular case, I do not have bathymetry data.  The surface elevations are derived from airborne lidar sources which generally do not penetrate water. I'll look up the Beer-Lambert law as lightxbulb suggested.  And, finally, thank you pmw1234 s for the compliment on the rendering.